# Using "UPDATE" and "SET" in Python to Update Snowflake Table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have been using Python to read and write data to Snowflake for some time now to **a table I have full update rights to** using a Snowflake helper class my colleague found on the internet. Please see below for the class I have been using with my personal Snowflake connection information abstracted and a simply read query that works given you have a 'TEST' table in your schema.

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import keyring
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import text

# Pull the username and password to be used to connect to snowflake
stored_username = keyring.get_password('my_username', 'username')
stored_password = keyring.get_password('my_password', 'password')

class SNOWDBHelper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = stored_username
        self.password = stored_password
        self.account = 'account'
        self.authenticator = 'authenticator'
        self.role = stored_username + '_DEV_ROLE'
        self.warehouse = 'warehouse'
        self.database = 'database'
        self.schema = 'schema'

    def __connect__(self):
        self.url = URL(
            user=stored_username,
            password=stored_password,
            account='account',
            authenticator='authenticator',
            role=stored_username + '_DEV_ROLE',
            warehouse='warehouse',
            database='database',
            schema='schema'

        )
        # =============================================================================
        self.url = URL(
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            account=self.account,
            authenticator=self.authenticator,
            role=self.role,
            warehouse=self.warehouse,
            database=self.database,
            schema=self.schema

        )
        self.engine = create_engine(self.url)
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()

    def __disconnect__(self):
        self.connection.close()

    def read(self, sql):
        self.__connect__()
        result = pd.read_sql_query(sql, self.engine)
        self.__disconnect__()
        return result

    def write(self, wdf, tablename):
        self.__connect__()
        wdf.to_sql(tablename.lower(), con=self.engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
        self.__disconnect__()

# Initiate the SnowDBHelper()
SNOWDB = SNOWDBHelper()

query = """SELECT * FROM """ + 'TEST'
snow_table = SNOWDB.read(query)
```

I now have the need to update an existing Snowflake table and my colleague suggested I could use the read function to send the query containing the update SQL to my Snowflake table. So I adapted an update query I use successfully in the Snowflake UI to update tables and used the read function to send it to Snowflake. **It actually tells me that the relevant rows in the table have been updated, but they have not.** Please see below for update query I use to attempt to change a field "field" in "test" table to "X" and the success message I get back. Not thrilled with this hacky update attempt method overall (where the table update is a side effect of sorts??), but could someone please help with method to update within this framework?

```
# Query I actually store in file: '0-Query-Update-Effective-Dating.sql'
UPDATE "Database"."Schema"."Test" AS UP
SET UP.FIELD = 'X'

# Read the query in from file and utilize it
update_test = open('0-Query-Update-Effective-Dating.sql')
update_query = text(update_test.read())
SNOWDB.read(update_query)

# Returns message of updated rows, but no rows updated
   number of rows updated  number of multi-joined rows updated
0                     316                                    0
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL2Pandas | UPDATE row(s) in pandas](https://sql2pandas.pythonanywhere.com/cookbook/sql-update-rows-in-pandas)